# R - How to create a forecast object from a pre-defined forecast, in order to apply accuracy() for MASE result

Tags: r, forecasting, mase, prophet

I am working with a forecast which has been created by Prophet. I would like to apply accuracy() to return the MASE after identifying this as the best accuracy measure for multiple forecasts, and will potentially want to do this for other forecasts created by more tools external to R and the fpp2 library. 
I understand that to do this I need to transform my forecast data into a valid forecast object within R, containing the necessary attributes detailed on page 73 of the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf). I am struggling to do this.
The examples of accuracy() I have seen generally take input forecasts created within R, where a valid forecast object is returned.
My forecast contains the historic data as well which I understand is needed for the MASE, and each observation is a minute apart.
Loading this into R from a csv, the typeof() returns "list". There are 2 columns - 'ds' is the timestamp and 'yhat' is the forecast value.

```
                     ds     yhat
1   2020-03-11 12:24:10 4.753588
2   2020-03-11 12:25:10 4.761864
3   2020-03-11 12:26:10 4.770209
4   2020-03-11 12:27:10 4.778622
5   2020-03-11 12:28:10 4.787102
```

I also have the real data which is the same length as the forecast and in the same structure (1 timestamp, 1 value) so plan to split this to supply a test set to pass into accuracy, which will overlap with the latter part of the forecast. I understand that MASE will use the historic data in the forecast to do the naive forecast used to compare to the prophet one.

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244506/measuring-var-accuracy-using-accuracy-from-forecast) which contains a code example from Rob J Hyndman of how to create a forecast object manually, however am really struggling to understand how to apply it in my case.

```
trainingdata <- window(Canada, end=c(1998,4))
testdata <- window(Canada, start=c(1999,1))
v <- VAR(trainingdata, p=2)
p <- predict(v, n.ahead=8)
res <- residuals(v)
fits <- fitted(v)
for(i in 1:4)
{
  fc <- structure(list(mean=p$fcst[[i]][,"fcst"], x=trainingdata[,i],
     fitted=c(NA,NA,fits[,i])),class="forecast")
  print(accuracy(fc,testdata[,i]))
}
```

forecast looks like this;

```
> dput(head(fc,30))
structure(list(ds = structure(c(1583929450, 1583929510, 1583929570, 
1583929630, 1583929690, 1583929750, 1583929810, 1583929870, 1583929930, 
1583929990, 1583930050, 1583930110, 1583930170, 1583930230, 1583930290, 
1583930350, 1583930410, 1583930470, 1583930530, 1583930590, 1583930650, 
1583930710, 1583930770, 1583930830, 1583930890, 1583930950, 1583931010, 
1583931070, 1583931130, 1583931190), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "GMT"), yhat = c(4.75358821574485, 4.76186444912349, 
4.77020922583557, 4.77862189668765, 4.7871017967275, 4.79564824550219, 
4.80426054708099, 4.8129379903282, 4.82167984892132, 4.83048538154093, 
4.83935383208194, 4.84828442972337, 4.85727638911008, 4.86632891060058, 
4.87544118025621, 4.8846123702249, 4.89384163876117, 4.90312813043914, 
4.9124709764005, 4.92186929447396, 4.93132218933035, 4.94082875282489, 
4.95038806397134, 4.95999918935695, 4.9696611832787, 4.97937308777942, 
4.98913393315992, 4.99894273795359, 5.00879850920808, 5.01870024280038
)), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Apologies i have only started using R in the past couple of days so getting up to speed. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include (a minimal except) your data in a format we can simply include in our scripts? Best to include the output of calls to `dput()`.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for your response. I have added in the output of the first 30 values of the forecast, does this help? When I try to do the same on the real data, it is outputting every single timestamp rather than just the first 30 within a class - "factor", I am not sure why this is.

Comment: I understand you're a new R user, and a built-in function may be easier, but why not just manually create the calculation for MASE? Forecast accuracy metrics are generally easy to understand and implement, both mathematically and syntactically. If you're going to be using R for analysis in the future you'll likely need to learn how to do these operations anyway on data frames.